# I am trying to print the current screen on Flutter Web, but I get an empty screen

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, printing, flutter-web

I am using flutter for the web,

I am trying to print the current screen using a JavaScript function called window.print()

but I got blank screen

note: I tried to use printing package with flutter but it's not working in my case

- this is the JavaScript function :

[image]

- and I call it there like this :

[image]

trying to print the current screen with flutter web and I was expecting to print the whole screen not an empty one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found a way to solve this problem (using flutter not JavaScript)

1- first thing I created an image of the widget that I want to print by using this package
https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot

2-after this I added this image into pdf by using pdf package
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

3- finally using the printing package I was able to print the pdf
https://pub.dev/packages/printing